# How do I parse a string in python multiple times?

Tags: python

i have a custom script i want to extract data from with python, but the only way i can think is to take out the marked bits then leave the unmarked bits like "go up" "go down" in this example.

```
string_a = [start]go up[wait time=500]go down[p]
string_b = @onclick go up[wait time=500]go down active="False"
```

In trying to do so, all I managed to do was extract the marked bits, but i cant figure out a way to save the data that isnt marked! it always gets lost when i extract the other bits!
this is the function im using to extract them. I call it multiple times in order to whittle away the markers, but I can't choose the order they get extracted in!

```
class Parsers:

  @staticmethod
  def extract(line, filters='[]'):
    #@retval list
    substring=line[:]
    contents=[]
    for bracket in range(line.count(str(filters[0]))):
      startend =[]
      for f in filters:
        now= substring.find(f)
        startend.append(now)
      contents.append(substring[startend[0]+1:startend[1]])
      substring=substring[startend[1]+1:]
    return contents, substring
```

btw the order im calling it at the moment is like this. i think i should put the order back to the @ being first, but i dont want to break it again.

```
star_string, first = Parsers.extract(string_a, filters='* ')
bracket_string, substring = Parsers.extract(string_a, filters='[]')
at_string, final = Parsers.extract(substring, filters='@ ')
```

please excuse my bad python, I learnt this all on my own and im still figuring this out.

Comment: This is Python, not Java - no need to create a class just for creating a class. If all you need is an `extract` function, just create the function at the modulevelvel  - no need for `staticmethod` there.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some mighty malabarisms with Python string methods above - but if all you want is to extract the content within brackets, and get the remainder of the string, that would be an eaasier thing with regular expressions (in Python, the "re" module)

```
import re
string_a = "[start]go up[wait time=500]go down[p]"
expr = r"\[.*?\]"
expr = re.compile(r"\[.*?\]")
contents = expr.findall(string_a)
substring = expr.sub("", string_a)
```

This simply tells the regexp engine to match for a literal `[`, and whatever characters are there(`.*`) up to the following `]` (`?` is used to match the next ], and not the last one)  - the `findall` call gets all such matches as a list of strings, and the  `sub` call replaces all the matches for an empty string.

For nice that regular expressions are, they are less Python than their own sub-programing language. Check the documentation on them: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Still, a simpler way of doing what you had done is to check character by character, and  have some variables to "know"  where you are in the string (if inside a tag or not, for example) - just like we would think about the problem if we could look at only one character at a time. I will write the code thinking on Python 3.x - if you are still using Python 2.x, please convert your strings to unicode objects before trying something like this:

```
def extract(line, filters='[]'):
    substring = ""
    contents = []
    inside_tag = False
    partial_tag = ""
    for char  in line:
        if char == filters[0] and not inside_tag:
            inside_tag = True
        elif char == filters[1] and inside_tag:
            contents.append(partial_tag)
            partial_tag = ""
            inside_tag = False
        elif inside_tag:
            partial_tag += char
        else:
            substring += 1
    if partial_tag:
        print("Warning: unclosed tag '{}' ".format(partial_tag))
    return contents, substring
```

Perceive as there is no need of complicated calculations of where each bracket falls in the line, and so on  - you just get them all.

Comment: TIL: malabarismo == mental juggling/acrobatics

Comment: Yes that - English is a nice language to swallow up these foreign words.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand this fully - you want to get `[stuff in brackets]` and `everything else`? If you are just parsing flat strings - no recursive brackets-in-brackets - you can do

```
import re

parse = re.compile(r"\[.*?\]|[^\[]+").findall
```

then

```
>>> parse('[start]go up[wait time=500]go down[p]')
['[start]', 'go up', '[wait time=500]', 'go down', '[p]']

>>> parse('@onclick go up[wait time=500]go down active="False"')
['@onclick go up', '[wait time=500]', 'go down active="False"']
```

The regex translates as "everything between two square brackets OR anything up to but not including an opening square bracket".

If this isn't what you wanted - do you want `@word` to be a separate chunk? - please show what `string_a` and `string_b` *should* be parsed as!